# Excel 2016: color cel in sheet 1 if not found anyware in sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, conditional-formatting

To see visually (with a color) if there are differences in my comparision I would like a VLOOKUP or VB or Conditional Formatting to show me which cells are different in Sheet 2.

example:

Sheet1, start in cel A1 for the headers

```
 - names>>>firstname>>>address  
 - goodyear>>>richie>>>Longstreet 15,somewhere
 - lastgood>>>franky>>>anyware 12, sierra
 - fella>>>mark>>>septemberroad 1, there,
```

Sheet2, start in cel A1 for the headers

```
 - names>>>firstnames>>>address
 - loveletter>>>mary>>>aroad 8, tumble
 - goodyear>>>richie>>>longstreet 15, somewhere
 - lastgood>>>franky>>>anyware 12, sierra
 - fella>>>mark>>>septemberroad 1, there
```

so in this case "loveletter mary" should be in red in sheet 2

How can that be done please? Knowing that the answer can be anywhere in sheet 2, not per definition on the same row as sheet 1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `COUNTIF` may do the job. That said, how can "loveletter mary" be red in sheet **1** if it doesn't appear there? You say data in Sheet 2 will not be in the same row as sheet 1. Will it be in the same column?

Comment: And vb.net is for visual studios, vba is for Excel.

Comment: Can you provide your `VLookUp` formula? If `VLookUp` doesn't return anything, you can use `Conditional formatting` to change the colour of your cell/row

Comment: So you're trying to Match a row's data (which outputs the row in the source data set) ,then apply a color when match reports an error (of if you use iferror(,0) a 0).  hello formula for conditional formatting.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad:  yes you're right! I ment to be red in sheet 2 if there are differences.

Comment: @ScottCraner: thanks, got it  ;-)

Comment: @Zac: I'm doing it manually. It takes me to much time too surch for it. My project has priority. But thanks anyways.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55066731/edit) to clarify this, so others don't need to dig through comments to find additional info

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad   Ok, done.